# How to pass 2 props on one onClick/onPress method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, redux

I am working with a React app and I need to pass down an id to a modal which is open on an onClick/onPress method.

The component below is a component I am going to use to render some data coming from an array, it is the component from where the modal is call:

```
// imports ...

import {
  passengerCardIdAction,
  pickupPassengerCardIdAction,,
} from '../../screens/HomeScreen/actions/homeScreen';

const PassengersInfo = ({
  id, // THIS IS THE ID I NEED
  name,
  address,
  datetime,
  callModal,
  cardinalpoint,
  navigationStore,
}) => {

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <View>
         // MAYBE I CAN SET SOMETHING HERE WHERE I GRAB THE ID 
         // ON THE onPress METHOD ALONG WITH THE CALL MODAL FUNCTION
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={callModal}>         
           CALL MODAL
         </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>    
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default compose(
  connect(
    store => ({
      passengerCardId: store.homeScreen.passengerCardId,
      pickupPassengerCardId: store.homeScreen.pickupPassengerCardId,
    }),
    dispatch => ({
      passengerCardIdActionHandler: id => {
        dispatch(passengerCardIdAction(id));
      },
      pickupPassengerCardIdActionHandler: id => {
        dispatch(pickupPassengerCardIdAction(id));
      },       
    }),
  ),
)(PassengersInfo);
```

Then, that component is call here:

```
class PassengerCardBasedOnRoute extends Component {

  const { popupsModalsActionHandler, searchParam } = this.props;
  render() {
    return (
     {passengerInfo.map(info => (
      <View key={info.id}>
        <PassengersInfo
          id={info.id}
          name={info.name}
          address={info.address}
          datetime={info.timestamp}
          searchParam={searchParam}
          cardinalpoint={info.cardinalpoint}
          callModal={popupsModalsActionHandler}
        />
      </View>
     )}
    );
  }
};

export default compose(
  connect(
    store => ({
      searchParam: store.homeScreen.searchParam,
      navigationStore: store.homeScreen.navigation,
      passengerCardId: store.homeScreen.passengerCardId,
      allPassengersDropOffOptionsPopup:
        store.popupsModals.allPassengersDropOffOptionsPopup,
      pickupPassengerCardId: store.homeScreen.pickupPassengerCardId,
    }),
    dispatch => ({
      popupsModalsActionHandler: data => {
        dispatch(popupsModalsAction(data));
      },
      passengerCardIdActionHandler: id => {
        dispatch(passengerCardIdAction(id));
      },
      pickupPassengerCardIdActionHandler: id => {
        dispatch(pickupPassengerCardIdAction(id));
      },
    }),
  ),
)(PassengerCardBasedOnRoute);
```

I can grab the ID and set it with Redux if that's an option.
Before, I was setting the modal info in the `PassengersInfo` component but as it is an array, the modal gets called around 40 times because that the times the parent component is render.

This is how I was doing it before:

```
    return (
     {passengerInfo.map(info => (
      <View key={info.id}>
        <OptionsModal>
          {
            <AllPassengersOptionsModal
              id={info.id}
              handleDeleteOptionsModal={() =>
                this.handleDeletePassenger(info.id)
              }
              handleCallOptionsModal={() =>
                Linking.openURL(`tel:${info.phone}`)
              }
            />
          }
        </OptionsModal>
        <PassengersInfo
          id={info.id}
          name={info.name}
          address={info.address}
          datetime={info.timestamp}
          searchParam={searchParam}
          cardinalpoint={info.cardinalpoint}
          callModal={popupsModalsActionHandler}
        />
      </View>
     )}
    );
```

So, in that way above I was getting the data exactly as I needed it. So how can I implement something to grab the ID I need? I need is the info on every card separately because the modal includes actions like `delete` and `call` specifically.

See the notes in my code.

**EDIT TO SHOW REDUCER AND ACTION**

action

```
export const popupsModalsAction = () => ({
  type: ActionTypes.TOGGLE_ALL_PASSENGERS_MODAL,
});
```

reducer

```
const initialState = {
  allPassengersDropOffOptionsPopup: false,
};

const handlers = {
  [ActionTypes.TOGGLE_ALL_PASSENGERS_MODAL](state) {
    return {
      ...state,
      allPassengersDropOffOptionsPopup: !state.allPassengersDropOffOptionsPopup,
    };
  },
};
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `onPress={() => callModal(id)}` ?

Comment: Hi @BrunoEduardo `callModal` is a prop, is that possible to do it like you are telling me? Like passing a a prop with a parameter?

Comment: Yeah, see my answer below. `callModal` contains a function signature, that's why you can call it like a normal function and pass t parameters.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `PassengerCardBasedOnRoute`'s `popupsModalsActionHandler` prop already has a parameter named `data`, use that to send your desired id:

```
<PassengersInfo
  id={info.id}
  name={info.name}
  address={info.address}
  datetime={info.timestamp}
  searchParam={searchParam}
  cardinalpoint={info.cardinalpoint}
  callModal={() => popupsModalsActionHandler(info.id)} // add which id you want to display in modal
/>
```

Now modify `popupsModalsAction` action creator to add a `visiblePassengerId` id in your action:

```
export const popupsModalsAction = (visiblePassengerId) => ({
  type: ActionTypes.TOGGLE_ALL_PASSENGERS_MODAL,
  visiblePassengerId
});
```

Then modify your reducer to store the `action.visiblePassengerId`:

```
const initialState = {
  allPassengersDropOffOptionsPopup: false,
  visiblePassengerId: null
};


function modalReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.TOGGLE_ALL_PASSENGERS_MODAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        allPassengersDropOffOptionsPopup: !state.allPassengersDropOffOptionsPopup,
        visiblePassengerId: action.visiblePassengerId // your action has a visiblePassengerId payload now, save it too
      };
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Now connect your Container to listen to the state changes:
(I don't know how you have defined the redux state, please make necessary adjustments)

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {open, passengerId, passengerInfo} = this.props;
    if(!open) return null; // if the state is not open, don't render anything

    const info = passengerInfo[passengerId]; // otherwise get the info using the id

    return (
      <OptionsModal>
        <AllPassengersOptionsModal
          id={info.id}
          //... other things
        />
      </OptionsModal>
    )
  }
}

// change depending on your redux state
export default connect(state => ({
  open: state.foo.allPassengersDropOffOptionsPopup, // modified by the reducer above
  passengerId: state.foo.visiblePassengerId,  // modified by the reducer above
  passengerInfo: state.bar.passengerInfo // all passengers info, we will get the one using passengerId
}, 
  dispatch => (
    // add as you need them
  )
))(Modal)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass an arrow function to `onPress`, like so: `onPress={() => callModal(this.props.id)}`.

Here's an example function that I use in one of my side projects:

```js
static propTypes = {
        id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        callbackReroll: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

rerollButtonPress = () => {
        this.props.callbackReroll(this.props.id);
        this.swipeRowRef.closeRow();
}

render() {
  return(
    <TouchableRipple
    onPress={this.rerollButtonPress}>
       ...
    </TouchableRipple>
  );
}
```

This way you can pass props as arguments.

**EDIT:** Since you want to use Redux to control when the modal open and closes, as well as the data it shows, here's a generic example of what you could do:

- Create a Reducer to handle your Modal

```js
const initialState = {
  shouldModalOpen: false,
  modalData: {},
};

const handlers = {
  [ActionTypes.TOGGLE_MODAL](state, { data }) {
    return {
      ...state,
      shouldModalOpen: !state.shouldModalOpen
      modalData: data,
    };
  },
};
```

- Connect the component that calls your modal to Redux and check for the `shouldModalOpen` flag:

```js
<View>
    <OptionsModal>
        {
          this.props.shouldModalOpen
            ? <AllPassengersOptionsModal
              data={this.props.modalData} />
            : null;          
        }
    </OptionsModal>
</View>
```

Comment: Yeah but, how do I grab that value when I call AllPassengersOptionsModal? Like here: `<AllPassengersOptionsModal id={THE_ID}>...`

Comment: Right now your code will end up calling `popupsModalsActionHandler` which will dispatch a Redux action. You could instead make it call a function that creates and show a `AllPassengersOptionsModal` instance. Or you could set the data in a redux store and along with a flag telling the code to show your modal. Depends on how you want to approach the modal creation and exhibition, really.

Comment: Yeah. That's why I asked about how to pass 2 props. But your solution is pretty good. It is just that I don't know how to adapt it to my code. Look `callModal={popupsModalsActionHandler}` is in charge of setting `true` to show the modal. Look at my code update I just did. There is more information about redux.

Comment: Do you need to use Redux to show your modal or you don't care? Because I thing It'd be easier to drop the Redux flag. If you must use Redux to flag the modal open/close actions that's ok too, I just need to know what do you want to do specifically.

Comment: The best is to use Redux because that modal is going to be call in around 3-4 different components.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to add a generic example that you can adapt to your project. Gimme a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the parameters you need as an argument to the function being called.

Try this option with the expected parameters of popupsModalsActionHandler.

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => callModal(id)}>         
   CALL MODAL
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: And how do I grab that value when I call `AllPassengersOptionsModal`? Like here: `<AllPassengersOptionsModal id={THE_ID}>...`

Answer (score 0):

You can either simply call the callModal with id using an anonymous function or pass it a function that has id as its argument using bind.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
  callModal(id)
}}>         
  CALL MODAL
</TouchableOpacity>
```

OR

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={callModal.bind(null,id)}>         
  CALL MODAL
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Yeah but, how do I grab that value when I call AllPassengersOptionsModal? Like here: `<AllPassengersOptionsModal id={THE_ID}>...`

Comment: You are passing the `id` as a prop to `PassengersInfo` component which is getting passed as an argument to the `callModal(id)`. You're getting the `id` in `AllPassengersOptionsModal` from info.

Comment: Yeah. That's why I asked about how to pass 2 props. But your solution is pretty good. It is just that I don't know how to adapt it to my code. Look `callModal={popupsModalsActionHandler}` is in charge of setting `true` to show the modal. Look at my code update I just did. There is more information about redux.